# Do we have such expressions as "the holiest" in the New Testament Greek?

Tags: textual-criticism

Do we have such expressions as "the holiest" in the New Testament Greek? Is there a superlative of "holy" in Old Greek at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You form a superlatives by taking the adjective ἅγιος (holy) and adding ατοτος. I have not yet found any occurrences of this word in the Greek New Testament.

EDIT:

I believe that `τῇ ἁγιωτάτῃ ... πίστει` is the predicative position which would lead to an intensification of the adjective. "Most holy faith" is an interpretation of the emphasis, but not a strict superlative (Jude 20). It's more along the lines of bolding something that you read with emphasis in your head, "... building yourselves up in your **holy** faith ..."

Hebrews 9:3 is `Ἅγια  Ἁγίων` which is just "Holy of Holy [ones/things/ideas/places]" which is usually reduced to "Holy of Holies." This is conceptually parallel to the English idea of "The Good, The Bad, and The Ugly." They're substantive adjectives - adjectives that take on the function of a noun. Given the OT imagery that runs through Hebrews, this would have been a natural connection to make to the inner room of the tabernacle.

Comment: "You form a superlatives by taking the adjective ἅγιος (holy) and adding ατοτος. I have not yet found any occurrences of this word in the Greek New Testament" - What about prepending πᾶς ('all') to an adjective? I mean such cases like παντοκράτωρ ('almighty') or παναγιότης ('all-holiness'). Do we have anything like that in the New Testament?

Answer (score 1):

These are the closest phrases I could find:

> But you, beloved, building yourselves up on your **most holy** faith, praying in the Holy Spirit [***-Jude 1:20***](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Jude%201:20&version=NASB)
>
> Behind the second veil there was a tabernacle which is called the **Holy of Holies** [***-Hebrews 9:3***](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Hebrews%209:3&version=NASB)

In the Greek text, [Jude](http://www.blueletterbible.org/Bible.cfm?b=Jud&c=1&t=NASB#conc/20) uses ἁγιωτάτῃ and [Hebrews](http://www.blueletterbible.org/Bible.cfm?b=Hbr&c=9&v=3&t=NASB#conc/3) uses  Ἅγια Ἁγίων.

Comment: If anyone would care to explain how to insert the Greek language into my post next time, that would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Now that I got over my confusion, I added a bit of Greek into the post.  I basically copy-and-paste from the [Blue Letter Bible](http://www.blueletterbible.org/index.cfm) webpage.  You need to press the little `C` icon next to a verse in order to see the Greek/Hebrew/Aramaic original.